# Is there a free tone generator for OS X that can be "dialed" in real time?

Tags: macos, audio

I am in need of a free tone generator (enter a frequency to output) for Mac OS X that can be "dialed" in real time. I need to be able to adjust a slider without having to stop/start/type in a new value. I have not been able to find a single application that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

[Audio Signal Generator](https://code.google.com/p/audiotools/downloads/detail?name=SigGen-1.0.dmg) by Bill Farmer, GPLv2 licensed.

It doesn't have a "slider" per se, but its knob dial might just be enough.

If you want something more complete and don't mind parting 5 USD, [AudioTest](http://www.katsurashareware.com/pgs/audiotest.html) from Katsura Shareware is also very usable, with a slider.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tone generator / tuner application that I wrote, available for free online:

[Tinnitus Sound Therapy Treatment - Tone generator & Tuner](http://www.audionotch.com/app/tune/)

It was originally to help people with tinnitus find the frequency their ears are ringing at, but it certainly has other uses.